# css - alternatives or hacks for mobile browsers that don't support "background-position"

Tags: css, mobile, opera, opera-mini

I am trying to make my mobile site accessible to as many browsers as possible, and I noticed when using the opera mini simulator (http://www.opera.com/mobile/demo/) that it doesn't support css background position - which I'm using to display a sprite for all of my site images. Are there any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has to be something else that keeps your code from working, because Opera Mini 6 does actually support background position.

Th website of the company that I am working for uses background position in some places, for example to change the color of the active menu button, and that works just fine. On the other hand there is some other rendering problem that makes it only show part of the button, but that part is the right color...

Comment: how are they changing the background? I am using jquery, like this: vehicleImage.css('backgroundPositionX',vehicleBGPos + 'px');

Comment: @mheavers: The `backgroundPositionX` attribute is non-standard and is only supported on some browsers. Use the `backgroundPosition` attribute and it will work in all current browsers.

Comment: Doesn't work. jQuery doesn't natively support backgroundPosition, so you have to use a plugin, and the plugin won't work in opera.

Comment: @mheavers: You don't need a plugin, you can use jQuery to set any style. It doesn't care what the style is called. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/BbN7j/

Comment: Ah - my problem was that I was trying to animate background position. Thanks Guffa - I removed the animation and switched to backgroundPosition and everything's working.